# How to use java mapping in mule?

Tags: java, mule

i get payload in below java format:

```
[
      {emai:'xyz@gmail.com',id:a1},
      {emai:'xyz@gmail.com',id:a2},
      {emai:'abc@gmail.com',id:a3},
      ....
]
```

the above input i is sent to java component which which need to give output in below format

```
[
      {emai:'xyz@gmail.com',id:[a1,a2]},
      {emai:'abc@gmail.com',id:a3},
      ....
]
```

i.e i need to combine all the id of a email into single array.

can anybody share the link to write java code? or any sample code?

Thanks..,

Comment: Is the payload a JSON object?

Comment: payload is, collection of objects. payload is response from salesforce select query, i.e select email,id from contacts

Comment: What kind of data type are you using to store that? Help me so I can help you with the code.

Comment: both are strings

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with Mule probably. Assuming you have a class `Input` and `Output` representing your corresponding List elements you can write:

```
public static class Output {
    private String email;
    private List<String> id;

    public Output(String email, List<String> id) {
        this.email = email;
        this.id = id;
    }
    // .. getters
}

public static class Input {
    private String email;
    private String id;

    public Input(String email, String id) {
        this.email = email;
        this.id = id;
    }
    // .. getters
}

@Test
public void test() {
    List<Input> inputs = Arrays.asList(
            new Input("xyz@gmail.com", "a1"),
            new Input("xyz@gmail.com", "a2"),
            new Input("abc@gmail.com", "a3")
    );

    List<Output> results = inputs.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Input::getEmail))
            .entrySet().stream().map(e->
                    new Output(e.getKey(),
                            e.getValue().stream().map(Input::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())
                    )
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(results);
}
```

And your input list will be converted to the desired format. I assume you can figure out how to transform whatever format you're sending and receiving to POJOs in Mule.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following dataweave code

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload groupBy $.emai map {
    emai : $.emai[0],
    id : $.id
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, in this case i get some email fields as empty also, i'm getting "Cannot coerce a :null to a :string." error

Comment: put filter on payload to check valid data then map it. Please check more details about filter [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#filter)

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

private final static String s = "[{emai:'xyz@gmail.com',id:a1},{emai:'xyz@gmail.com',id:a2},{emai:'abc@gmail.com',id:a3},....]";

public static void main(final String[] argv) throws JSONException {
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
//Turn the payload into a JSONArray
JSONArray new_arry=new JSONArray();
int payload_length = array.length();
ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<payload_length;i++){
//For every email, use combine to add ids into a JSONArray and attach it to 
//a single email
String email = array.getJSONObject(i).get("email").toString();
//If email has been already considered, skip the check for it
if(array.contains(email))
continue;
else{
emails.add(email);
JSONArray combine = new JSONArray();
for(j=i;j<payload_length;j++){
if(array.get(j).get("email").toString()==email)
combine.put(array.get(j).get("id").toString();
    }
new_array.put(new JSONObject().(email,combine);
   }
}
```